# JavaScript - Instantiate a object and assign it to another existing variable?

Tags: javascript, instantiation

Been trying to instantiate an object (called "isSize" below) and assign it to another existing variable (called "sizeObject"), here is the first object ("isSize") within a function:

```
function Size(isSize) {
this.isSize = 80;
setSize(this.isSize);
}
```

And here's the second variable of which I want to assign the previous variable to:

```
var sizeObject;
```

I've been trying various ways such as the following:

```
function createSize(isSize){
var isSize = new sizeObject();
}
```

Anyone got any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: You've said "isSize" is an object, but you're using it as a property and setting its value to 80. Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry should of given more information. 
I've been tasked some work for University, which I'll explain.
I needed to create a Size class which defines a instance variable called "isSize", and which the constructor function should set the initial value of the "isSize" variable to 80.
Next, I need to add code to the "createSize" function which should instantiate a Size object and assign it the the already existing (the variable was created by the lecturer) "sizeObject".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your comment correctly, here is what you are looking for:

```
// this is the constructor of the `Size` class
function Size() {
  this.isSize = 80;
}

function createSize() {
  // add this line:
  var sizeObject = new Size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to understand quite what you're asking, but this:

```
var sizeObject = new Size(20);
```

...will create a new object with a `isSize` property on it with the value 20 if you change `Size` to:

```
function Size(initialSize) {
    this.isSize = initialSize;
}
```

(E.g., so it actually uses the argument you give it, rather than using an hardcoded `80`.)

`Size` in the above is a *constructor function*. You use constructor functions via `new`.